# Angular looping multi dimensional json object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

i'm practicing with angular and thought it would be cool to make a shopping cart, I have downloaded a pre-made site template that displays items in categories but the way its layed out is pretty much like

```
<div class="row">
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So every row in the category grid is a div containing an un ordered list of 3 items

Here is my angular code:

```
<div ng-app="CategoryLoader" ng-controller="CatLoader">
    <div ng-repeat="row in items">
    <ul>
        <li class="new" ng-repeat="item in row">
            <div class="catThum"><img src="http://cart.asccio.net/images/OXO---Homepage_39.jpg" alt="" /><div class="new"></div></div>
            <div class="catDetail">
                <h4><a href="#">{{item.name}}</a></h4>
                <p>{{item.price}}</p>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("CategoryLoader", []);
    app.controller("CatLoader", function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://cart.asccio.net/category/items/7').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.items = data;
                alert("Loaded all items");

            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // log error
                alert("error");
            });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see ive split the json data into 3 items per segment so it should work well with the design however only one item is displaying and i'm getting this error in my browser console

```
"[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector" jquery.cycle.js:10:180
"Error: this.parentNode is null
jQuery.prototype.after/<@http://cart.asccio.net/js/jquery-1.3.2.js:274:4
jQuery.prototype.domManip@http://cart.asccio.net/js/jquery-1.3.2.js:522:1
jQuery.prototype.after@http://cart.asccio.net/js/jquery-1.3.2.js:273:1
Sd</this.$get</<.enter@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:140:127
ue</<.link/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:185:315
B/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:41:449
W/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:43:170
A@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:46:352
ue</<.link/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:185:1
zd/this.$get</h.prototype.$watchCollection/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:98:313
zd/this.$get</h.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:99:209
zd/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:101:473
f@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:66:319
F@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:70:242
md/</B.onreadystatechange@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:71:277
```

Image of the rendered result:
[image]

Image of what it 'should' look like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide a fiddle with the json data and your problem

Comment: error seems to happen in ```jquery.cycle.js```, as the output shows, but we don't see anything setting up or using jquery.cycle in the code you provided.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ds4tn1q4/ put the raw json data into the script and it seems to work now ? haha

Answer (score 0):

I was including Jquery libraries as well as the angular.js library this was causing problems, most likely comparability issues.

Works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Let debug it, add some lines:

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // print to console windows
    alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // or popup a window
    $scope.items = data;
}
```